# iOS Stateless/Valueless Progress Bar?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uiprogressview

I'm looking to get a stateless/valueless UIProgressView or other kind of progress bar in iOS:

[image]

I've tried looking up some documentation but couldn't find anything relevant to my issue.
If any of you have any recommendations i'd love to hear those :)

Thanks!
Shai.

Comment: there is the UIActivityIndicator(spinner), which is generally used where values cannot be determined for any activity... but it certainly doesnt look like that bar.

Comment: Yeah , I'm aware of UIActivityIndicator but thats not what i'm looking for :) I'm looking for a UIProgressView that would act as an activity indicator.

Comment: ah! i think its possible to mimic the bar with a uiprogressbar(setting the trackimage and stuff and making the progress move to zero after it crosses a certain pixel), but that would kinda defeat the "progress" in the bar :D

Comment: @govi I'll just go to a PNG Sequence, thanks anyways man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS's [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is designed specifically for that situation in which you know with certainty the percentage completed of your task. It only provides a 'fill-in' style presentation. You will not be able to use it for merely indicating an ongoing activity.

Ideas: use [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s capacity for animating through an array of images. You could create just a few (three or four) variants on what I will call the 'barbershop pole' progress image and use those. Or... just take that animated gif you posted and put it in your UIImageView. It will work fine. If you want to stop animating it... just do something like

```
[myImageView setImage:stoppedImage];
```

If you really want to get fancy, you could write some subclass to do everything you want. But who has the time? Keep it simple!

***Another thought***

Why didn't I just suggest that you use the animated gif you posted above in your image view? It will work. And be rather easy.

Comment: Yeah i guessed that UIImageView would be the way , i just hoped there's an easier iOS-way :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished a UIProgressView subclass that's super easy to use (if progress == 0 activate barber pole effect). Hope this helps!

[WNProgressView](https://github.com/n8chur/WNProgressView)

Comment: This is really good, works like a charm and it's much cleaner that the suggested solution to use a set of images.

Answer (score 1):

what about adding a UIImageView when the process begins? then hide it when finished? you will need to animate an image then. to do that. this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview) might help you

Comment: I could use a PNG Sequence, but thats a last resort, I'd rather have some sort of a controller if one is available.