# Play animated GIF image on UIImageView

Tags: arrays, uiimageview, animated-gif, xcode4.6

I've been looking all over Google for a way to "play" my animated gif, in a UIImageView from the StoryBoard (iOS6), with out using a Array or something.

Is there really no other way to view my gif, then make a Array with all the frames ?
If there is, please tell me how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add animated Gif image in Iphone UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview)