# UIImageView for showing the application loading progress

Tags: android, ios, iphone, uiimageview, mask

I have a launch screen which contains application logo, say [test](http://d.pr/i/EGDX).
As the application will start loading, the logo will gradually starts filling like [this](http://d.pr/i/EGDX). In the end, when the application will be loaded completely, it will look like [this](http://d.pr/i/Q886).

One point I would like to mention here is that the colour is being filled from left to right. And there will not be a single colour. It contains different colours for different characters.

After googling, I come to know that I need to use two images completely filled image with red colour and another one without colour, one on the top of other and apply animations on it. So far I did that, but not succeeded in animating it from left to right.

Same functionality I need to apply in android also. Can someone please suggest ?

Comment: You have elaborated the whole thing clearly.. one vote for that..

Comment: Can someone specify me same for android ?

Answer (score 2):

Have two images blank & filled overlapped with each other. Modify the width of filled image
on the fly depending on the progress.

```
static int max_image_width = 250

//assumption
UIImage *blankImage;
UIImage *filledImage;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self fillImage:1]; /*any value between 0 and 1 */
}

-(void)fillImage:(CGFloat)progress{

    CGFloat image_width = max_image_width * progress;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2  animations:^{

        CGRect frame = self.filledImage.frame;
        frame.size.width = image_width;
        self.filledImage.frame = frame;
    }];

}
```

Comment: @kunal-belani Thanks for the reply. But it does not add the animation which I require. As I have mentioned, the animation should be like filling the text colour from left to right slowly.

Comment: it does animate. You can set your animation duration and try it.I have tested this code.

Comment: It dose Kunal, but not the way I wanted. Possibly due to ios 7 and xcode 5.0.2. I have tested it in Xcode 5.0 and used ios7 as base sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do is that use `sprite sheet animation` in your iOS app, you can get the example from here http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/24/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-game-sprite/ OR you can use a `GIF Image` code support available here https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4386709/1042240 (SO's own answer)

Would be happy to hear what you try and implement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Glad to know that I have explained it properly.. :) Surely will go through your links and let you know the progress.

Comment: I can't use the gif images. Is there any option in animation to slowly make darker image visible from left to right ? Means the darker image will be there only just above the lighter image and opacity to 0. And while animating it, gradually increase the opacity to reassemble that we are redrawing the darker image from left to right.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But yes the problem solved by using animations only.

Comment: Ok thanks.. just select my answer as the correct one for that :)