# How to split animated GIF into an array of UIImages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, animated-gif

I need to do some processing on the individual frames of an animated `GIF` so I need to be able to split an animated `GIF`, do some processing and merge it back again into a `GIF`.

I know how to create an animated gif from separate `UIImages` but I don't know how to split the frames of a `GIF` into separate `UIImages`.

Could anyone share some code that can do this?

Comment: This question has already got an answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview

Comment: U could try `avconv -i "$file" fle-%05d.png`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Image I/O framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html) to load the frames of an animated GIF as individual `CGImage` objects, which you can then wrap in `UIImage` objects.

However, it would probably be much easier for you to just use [my public domain `UIImage+animatedGIF` category](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) to load the GIF into an animated `UIImage`, and then access the `images` property of the animated image to get the individual frames.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to give an example for who want or need to see an example code (how to use this framework with this issue) written in Swift 4 for IOS :

```
static func getSequence(gifNamed: String) -> [UIImage]? {
    
    guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main
        .url(forResource: gifNamed, withExtension: "gif") else {
            print("This image named \"\(gifNamed)\" does not exist!")
            return nil
    }
    
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
        print("Cannot turn image named \"\(gifNamed)\" into NSData")
        return nil
    }
    
    let gifOptions = [
        kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat as String : true as NSNumber,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform as String : true as NSNumber,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways as String : true as NSNumber
        ] as CFDictionary
    
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, gifOptions) else {
        debugPrint("Cannot create image source with data!")
        return nil
    }
    
    let framesCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(imageSource)
    var frameList = [UIImage]()
    
    for index in 0 ..< framesCount {
        
        if let cgImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, index, nil) {
            let uiImageRef = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef)
            frameList.append(uiImageRef)
        }
        
    }
    
    return frameList // Your gif frames is ready
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like Swift 3 solution, you can use `Decoder` from GifMagic https://github.com/onmyway133/GifMagic, which lets you access individual frame within the gif, and get additional gif infos, like size and delay time

```
let result = Decoder().decode(fileUrl: gifFileUrl)
```

Comment: In your github repo there is only Mac solution available. Can you also add support for iOS.