# How to start and end UIImageView animation with two different images?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

Im animating UIImageView with an array of images using method `[UIImageView startAnimating]`

**1**.At very start my `imageView` has an image `image1.png`.

**2**.In my image array i have 10 images which start with `image1.png` and ends with `image10.png`.

**Issue:** After completion of animation my imageView's image is `image1.png`,i want it to be `image10.png`.

How can i set `image10.png` as background of imageView on completion of animation?

Comment: Does the animation has to go through all the images in the array or just jump into the last one at the end?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview

Comment: it has to go through all images and after completion of this animation i want last image on imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the last object from the array like this.

```
 animationImageView.image=[images lastObject];
```

Comment: set animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; or to 1 and check.

Comment: self.aeIcon.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],...... [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"], nil];
                            self.aeIcon.animationDuration = 1.0f;
                            self.aeIcon.animationRepeatCount = 1;
                            [self.aeIcon startAnimating];
                            self.aeIcon.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"];