# How To Add UIButtons with GIF Background in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, ios9

I have found this code to add GIF Background on the landing screen and worked great,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MovingClouds", ofType: "gif")
    let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL())

    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)

    let filter = UIView()
    filter.frame = self.view.frame
    filter.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    filter.alpha = 0.05
    self.view.addSubview(filter)

    let welcomeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
    welcomeLabel.text = "KeepON"
    welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    welcomeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Zapfino", size: 35)
    welcomeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
}
```

this shows my GIF background and my Title, but When I try to add Buttons in story board in View Controller they don't appear when I run my app, only the GIF background with the title, and I don't want to add buttons using code.

So any ideas ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are adding subviews on top of the views that already exist. Instead of `addSubView`, use `insertSubView(webViewBG,atIndex:0);`

Comment: thanks , any idea about how to resize the GiF ? because it appear smaller with auto layout ON , thanks

Comment: This is a web view. So i have no idea,  is there any particular reason you want it as a web view?  Because uiimageview supports animation,  and it is a lot better than having a web browser for a view.   Btw if this answered your question please mark it as an answer so people know.

Comment: no there is no particular reason that was the only working solution I found, so I have to just choose my GIF as I choose a normal image ? and thanks for the info I didn't know that xD

Comment: Take a look at this, it will help you out.  If you go the ImageView route, it has scaling abilities for the image.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply, but the code you provided in link is in objective-c not swift 2 :/ !!

Comment: Can't hold your hand the entire way,  converting from objective C to swift 2 is really easy,  plus if you look at the other answers, sombody has posted a swift 2 answer

Comment: yes, but you could look at the objective C,  look at the swift, and learn how to get the answer from the 2