# How to get gif asset UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gif, animated-gif

How to load **animated GIF** image as *UIImage* from `*.imageset` folder with different resolutions, without any additional pods?

If i put my GIF images in `*.imageset` folder they correctly display in XCode http://take.ms/7fsCp, but when i try to load it with UIImage, it returns *nil*

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"help_image"];
```

How to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do that.

```
#import "UIImage+GIF.h"

self.imageViewGif.image= [UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"help_image"];
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I've already read this article before question, and thought about easier solution, without additional frameworks. Now use SD. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Add animated Gif image in Iphone UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview)

check this link you will get your answer Using UIImage category you can get the exect output.