# How to create a view that changes its gradient colors like Instagram in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, instagram, gradient

Instagram's log-in screen has a background view that changes it's colors through the use of gradients. How does it work?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Try to do something on you rown and show us a specific prbolem with your code included

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animated .gif to your background using a ImageView [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview) the Link.