# ".gif" File loads and then disappears after 1 second

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I am a beginner to **Swift**, so I would probably need some explaining. Please bear with me. I am creating an app that needs to load a `.gif` file, but when I run it on the simulator it loads for one second (or even less) and then becomes blank, but the screen itself stays on the page that had the `.gif` file on it. I'm not sure why this happens. Can someone explain? Thank you!

### Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func Burning(sender: AnyObject) {

        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fire", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let imageGif = UIImage.gifWithData(imageData!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageGif)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:414.0, height: 685.0)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    @IBAction func Smashing(sender: AnyObject) {


        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("water", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let imageGif = UIImage.gifWithData(imageData!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageGif)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:414.0, height: 685.0)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    @IBAction func Shredding(sender: AnyObject) {


        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("shredder", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let imageGif = UIImage.gifWithData(imageData!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageGif)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:414.0, height: 685.0)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: There is library called AsyncImageView. it takes a gif and show it to u, I recommend you to use it!

Comment: I'd recommend this: https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add animated Gif image in Iphone UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview)

Comment: @SHN I've tried all of those but they didn't work...

Comment: @CindyKim What is gifWithData method? Are you using SwiftGIf UIImage category? If yes then probably you need to share more info/code as SwiftGIF works fine, there should be some other problem with your code.

Comment: @CindyKim How did you fix this? I am running into similar issue