# GIF image not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, gif

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview) to show GIF image.

I have tried:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.gif"], nil];
    animatedImageView.animationDuration = 6.0f;
    animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 10;
    [animatedImageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I added GIF image to my project. But GIF image not show.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, the same link as I mention above.

Comment: oh ok sorry, if you want to play the single gif use UIWebview is the best option

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIWebview to load GIF image :

```
NSString *pathForFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"splash" ofType: @"gif"];
    NSData *dataOfGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForFile];
    [Web_View loadData:dataOfGif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Use code that I am using in my app :

```
NSString *pathForFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"splash" ofType: @"gif"];
    NSData *dataOfGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathForFile];

        UIWebView *Web_View = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [Web_View loadData:dataOfGif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
        [self.view addSubview:Web_View];
```

or Check this :

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Comment: Hi @Abhisheck Gupta, I have tried your code, but gif image not show.

Comment: @Khuong for me its working.Where you getting problem ??

Comment: Ahh, ok. But the frame of gif is not show correctly.

Comment: For me use UIWebView is kinda overkill for showing GIF, since webview have poor init time to render causing the view load slower, use external lib is better

Comment: Ok, I think I will use this https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 1):

Use this library ....

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

and put this code for load .gif file.

```
"YOURIMAGEVIEW".image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:"YOUR_URL_OF_IMAGE"]
```

Comment: Approve my answer @Khuong

Comment: No, just vote your answer. Because I can use some library to show gif image.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support GIF image, only sequence of static image that can chain to become animated, in your link they also split it to multiple frame to do it, you should use external library to play the GIF directly in `UIImageView`, check for some library in [awesome-ios](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#gif)