# How to Display GIF image from URL in Imageview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Earlier i used SDWebimage third party to display images, now i removed that 3rd party due some other reason. is there any other way to Display GIF image from URL in Imageview without using third party...

Comment: Download it with NSURLSession and display it?

Comment: @Vijayender Vaddepally search in google because you got multiple answer

Comment: Any possibility with AFNetworking?

Comment: i searched but i didn't get correct answer ...

Comment: GIF is not supported by `UIImagewView` directly. So you will either build your own GIF parse or use a thirdparty library,

Comment: That why i posted this question how can you give -vote ?

Comment: Because there are tons of answers of your question, search properly before asking a question.

Comment: I know Tons of answers available but that answers are older one. who knows  some body founded alternative answer for that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it simply by following next steps:

1. Add the following `functions`

   ```
   #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
   #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

   UIImage *GIFFromData(NSData *data) {
       if (!data) {
           return nil;
       }

       CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)(data), NULL);

       UIImage *image = nil;
       if (GIFSourceContainsAnimatedGIF(source)) {
           image = GIFFromImageSource(source);
       } else {
           image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
       }

       if (source) {
           CFRelease(source);
       }

       return image;
   }


   BOOL GIFSourceContainsAnimatedGIF(CGImageSourceRef source) {
       return (source && UTTypeConformsTo(CGImageSourceGetType(source), kUTTypeGIF) && CGImageSourceGetCount(source) > 1);
   }

   UIImage *GIFFromImageSource(CGImageSourceRef source) {
       CFRetain(source);
       NSUInteger numberOfFrames = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);
       NSMutableArray<UIImage *> *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfFrames];
       NSTimeInterval duration = 0.0;
       for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; ++i) {
           CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
           if (image) {
               UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
               [images addObject:frameImage];
               CFRelease(image);
           } else {
               continue;
           }

           duration += GIFSourceGetFrameDelay(source, i);
       }
       CFRelease(source);

       return [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:images duration:duration];
   }

   NSTimeInterval GIFSourceGetFrameDelay(CGImageSourceRef source, NSUInteger index) {
       NSTimeInterval frameDelay = 0;
       CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, index, NULL);
       if (!imageProperties) {
           return frameDelay;
       }

       CFDictionaryRef gifProperties = nil;
       if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary, (const void **)&gifProperties)) {
           const void *durationValue = nil;
           if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(gifProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime, &durationValue)) {
               frameDelay = [(__bridge NSNumber *)durationValue doubleValue];
               if (frameDelay <= 0) {
                   if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(gifProperties, kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime, &durationValue)) {
                       frameDelay = [(__bridge NSNumber *)durationValue doubleValue];
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       CFRelease(imageProperties);

       return frameDelay;
   }
   ```
2. Download your GIF with NSURLSession
3. Display it

   ```
   UIImage *image = GIFFromData(data);
   UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   ```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

[Add animated Gif image in Iphone UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview)