# How can I play more gif within the same time in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am developing an game in Objective-C.

So I need to set two gif in UIViewController that means, I need to set the background to the UIViewController as 1 video. Then at the centre of the UIViewController as other video. Condition is : Two gif should play together.

Comment: you have to run two different instances of videoPlayer at a time.

Comment: yes i need to play ,how to do

Comment: sorry , i need to play two gif at same time

Comment: how to set and code for this

Comment: please refer below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4386709/1746086

Comment: how to implement i not understood

Comment: suppose if two gif is used then how to implement

Comment: You probably need to use a third-party library that supports playing gifs, like https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif

Comment: how to display in the video in uiimageview in ios

Comment: can video can play in uiimageview