# How to use GIFs inside an iOS App without any Third Party Library using UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif

I am currently working on a project which depends heavily on GIFs. However, I never worked with GIFs in Swift for iOS before an I am pretty lost.

The first thing I tried was to import some GIFs to my `Assets.xcassets` folder. I realised that using an ImageSet for GIFs does not work.

**So my first Question:** How do I import GIFs into my project? And should I use only one resolution or are three the better way like for images?

Then I already checked out some questions about **presenting a GIF inside a** `UIImageView`, programmatically and via Storyboard. As I figured out, this is probably best possible by using an extension for the `UIImage` class. However, the Swift 4 examples didn't work for me because of some reason.

**So my second Question:** How do I use the imported GIFs inside my project and display them inside a `UIImageView` programmatically?

Comment: did you find anything i am facing same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually decode GIF data, then you will be able to show it frame-by-frame. You will not have any simple answers here, bcs that's definitely very hard idea, try copy decoding algorithm from Third-Party and player or just use it. Something like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) will be the best option for you. Check SDAnimatedImagePlayer, SDWebAnimatedImage classes.

Answer (score 2):

If your animated gif has a constant frame time for all frames then you can easily load it from your assets catalog without third party libraries with this:

```
extension UIImage {
    static func animatedGif(named: String, framesPerSecond: Double = 10) -> UIImage? {
        guard let asset = NSDataAsset(name: named) else { return nil }
        return animatedGif(from: asset.data, framesPerSecond: framesPerSecond)
    }

    static func animatedGif(from data: Data, framesPerSecond: Double = 10) -> UIImage? {
        guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else { return nil }
        let imageCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        var images: [UIImage] = []
        for i in 0 ..< imageCount {
            if let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
                images.append(UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))
            }
        }
        return UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: Double(images.count) / framesPerSecond)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set it on imageview

Comment: Same as any other UIImage should work imageView.image = UIImage.animatedGif(named: "imageName") assuming you added the gif to assets catalog as data asset.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGAnimateImageDataWithBlock` or `CGAnimateImageAtURLWithBlock` after iOS 13.

```
extension UIImageView: SupportProduct {
    
    public func load(name: String, in bundle: Bundle = .main) {
        if let data = NSDataAsset(name: name, bundle: bundle)?.data {
            CGAnimateImageDataWithBlock(data as CFData, nil) { (_, cgImage, _) in
                self.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to yycking's answer (I can't comment because of reputation), you have to stop 'CGAnimateImageDataWithBlock' manually. If not, it will still be animating even if UIImageView is nil.

So the final code is:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func loadGIF(name: String, in bundle: Bundle = .main) {
        if let data = NSDataAsset(name: name, bundle: bundle)?.data {
            CGAnimateImageDataWithBlock(data as CFData, nil) { [weak self] (index, cgImage, stop) in
                // NOTE: without 'stop.pointee = true', even if self is nil, animating will not be stopped
                guard let self = self else {
                    stop.pointee = true
                    return
                }
                self.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of problem to solve. I found answers in this thread helpful. Please check them out.
[Add animated Gif image in Iphone UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview)

Also, I highly recommend to checkout some implementations inside [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). It handles showing, playing and other functionalities you might need for GIFs in iOS.